# C# Export CSV file with semicolon

Tags: c#, csv, export

I want to convert an Excel file to csv and I wrote this C# code:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbooks workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
Excel.Workbook workBook = workBooks.Open(sourceFile,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ';',
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
workBook.SaveAs(csvFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
workBook.Close(false, sourceFile, null);
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
Excel.Application app = excelApp.Application;
app.Quit(); 
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
sourceFile = csvFilePath;
```

But the csv file is seperated with commas. I have searched on the internet. I tried Region Setting and other things, but none of them solved my problem.

Example output: `Hesap,391,TL,,,`

I want this output: `Hesap;391;TL;;;`

Comment: I dont understand ? why mean? I want to convert excel to csv file and process other thing. Thanks.

Comment: CSV is `comma seperated values` - why semicolon?

Comment: For example : Hesap,367.45,43 TL,Turkey,,, 367.45,43 TL this is currency if comma csv result will 367.45 , 43 TL . i dont want this. I hope I could explain what I am.

Comment: This is what I thought - you are worried that the `,` in your data will break the CSV. Just try it in Excel - it will automatically enclose any values which contain a `,` with quotes.

Comment: @ChrisBallard to be fair C could stand for "character". In principle, there's nothing preventing one from using ";", "|" or any other (reasonable) character to separate fields.

Comment: Fair enough! Even so, as I guessed I think OP is trying to solve a problem that doesn't need solving

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, - I had to migrate one project from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012, and this one

`workBook.SaveAs(csvFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

and csv file was separated with commas instead of semicolons.
I found one solution that helped me to avoid this problem

Formatting:

```
 oBook.SaveAs(newFileName, XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText,
            missing, missing, false, false,
            XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

And after I rewrite file this way:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(newFileName);
            text = text.Replace("\t", ";").Replace("{tab}", "\t");
            File.WriteAllText(newFileName, text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

So I have csv file separated by semicolons.
But another problem left - fileds with date and float values have another format, - date is 10/5/2015 18:54 instead of 5.10.2015 18:54 and float values 5.55 instead of 5,55.

I think the last two problems i will decide by converting vaules in my oracle procedures, but the main problem is passed - we have the same csv file we need.

Some of developers may suppose that comma is right and semicolon not or it is not difference between these delemiters, but if you have a big project there all procedures on the server side work in one way it is difficult to set and correct all of them.

And I don't understand one thing - if i have a comma in the field in excel file and i use this method workbook.SaveAs, how we will take correct value of the field further? - there will be two values instead of one! With semicolon situation is the same, but we never use semicolons in our Excel files.

Answer (score 2):

For German System Settings:

```
xlVorlBook.SaveAs(sDatei, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Local: true);
```

Just use the Local: true to change the Separator to **;**