# Exporting to csv in German notation

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export my `DataGrid` objects to a CSV file, and let the user have the option to see German notation on values of type `double`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv1)
    {
        double val;
        if (double.TryParse(dr.Cells[column.Name].Value.ToString(), out val))
        {
            sw.Write(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.0}", val));
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
}
```

`sw` here is a new `StreamWriter` object.
I'm using the correct culture for this, however when I see the results, I see what should, for example, have been "18,54", is 18, and in the cell right next to it there is a 5, followed by a dot (.). What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: What *is* `val`? Have you checked its value in the debugger?

Comment: ¿Are you opening it in excel? If so, try to separate values by semicolon instead of comma.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The whole string.Format line returns 18,5 (comma). val itself is 18.54 (dot)

Comment: And you need 18,54? -> {0:0.00}

Comment: @mattinsalto This gives me just 18, and 54 on the next cell. Does sw.Write(",") do this ?

Comment: am I right when I assume that you use an extra "," to separate each individual entry? so one line could look like 18,54,23,4 ?? or what is `sw.Write(",");` good for?

Comment: change sw.Write(","); to sw.Write(";");

Comment: You are at least missing one more digit after the dot: "{0:0.0}". The rest is about csv import..

Comment: What is the culture / format used in the strings displayed in the grid? (i.e. what is the result of `dr.Cells[column.Name].Value.ToString()`?)

Comment: Remember people, if you're using commas as your separator and also as your decimal notation, you're going to have issues. You need to make the CSV use a different separator than a comma. Otherwise 18,54 becomes the values 18 and 54!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem once.

The value is split into two cells because the german numerical comma "," is just the seperator in a csv. What I did was use semicolon ";" as a seperator, and OpenOffice somehow did the right thing. (either automatically, or I specified the encoding on opening, can't remember).

Oh, and I just found this on wikipedia:

```
Year;Make;Model;Length
1997;Ford;E350;2,34
2000;Mercury;Cougar;2,38
```

> The latter format is not RFC 4180 compliant. Compliance could be achieved by the ***use of a comma*** instead of a semicolon as a separator and either the international notation for the representation of the decimal mark or the practice of ***quoting all numbers*** that have a decimal mark.

So "1,2","3,4" should be correct.

Comment: Can you please give me the code representation of this?

Answer (score 1):

Thats what I've written in the comments:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv1)
        {
            double val;
            if (double.TryParse(dr.Cells[column.Name].Value.ToString(), out val))
            {
                sw.Write(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.00}", val));
                sw.Write(";");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem persists: 18 in oe cell and 54 in the next.

Comment: @Iason Have you changed the CSV type to dictate that it is using a semi colon as the splitter. [Look here for an example of making a CSV file with different delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480669/c-sharp-export-csv-file-with-semicolon)

Comment: Ok, I will need to test this tomorrow. But there is the possibility that I will also need to have the , delimiter for other data. I don't know if I can set the delimiter dynamically.

Comment: You could wrap the text with double quotes and continue using comma as separator: sw.Write("\""+string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.00}", val)+"\"");

Answer (score 0):

You only show one place after the point/comma. if you replace "{0:0.0}" with "{0:0.00}", it should show 18,54. For more information on formating floating-point numbers see this site: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

The comma is the german character that is used instead of a dot, so it doesn't work well on csv. Thats wihy your Result is 18,5,... You should replace your sw.Write(","); with sw.Write(";"); or another character, or use quoutation marks around your numbers.

Comment: This for some reason shows 18 in one cell and 54 in the next.

Comment: Thats because you use the cell delimter(',') also for the number. You should try sw.Write(","); or put qoutation marks around the numbers.